# server share mount error in WSL2 error13

Tags: mount, samba, cifs

my `/etc/fstab` is as:

```
//server-ip/path/share/ /mnt/d/wsl2/local/path cifs domain=my.domain.com,username="abc",password="123",rw,uid=1000,gid=1000 1 0
```

which works fine in a remote ubuntu, but in my local WSL2 system, when `sudo mount -a` (same as i did at remote ubuntu) got error:

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg
```

not familiar with mount/cifs stuff, but how can it be fixed?

thanks very much.

Comment: did you look at the `kernel log messages` like the error suggests, or the manual? is `server-ip` your public IP?

Comment: hi, `dmesg` says ` CIFS: Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE`,  and my wsl2 ip indeed is not a legal domain ip, but can i change the wsl2 ip manually?

Comment: I didn't ask what the wsl2 IP was, I asked if `server-ip` is a public or so called "private" ip address .... `STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE` suggests you're using incorrect credentials - perhaps you're reaching a different server to the one you expect. Does your router have samba shares for example?

Comment: thanks for advice, i mean i not sure if this is the reason for my case: i'm in a company network, the share-server restricts ip like 172.168.10.x to get access, my pc(win10) and remote ubuntu both have legal ip, but ip of wsl2 (ifconfig in wsl2) is 192.168.x.y, i thougt this is why wsl can not mount share (like pc and remote ubuntu do)?

Comment: what is a `legal ip`?? you mean one that is allowed by the share server?

Comment: yes, i think so, the share-server will restrict only allowed ip to get access, i,m not sure if i can manually set wsl2 a legal ip without conflict with other ip on the net.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142690/discussion-between-furynerd-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: hi @JaromandaX, as i said, i am not familiar with these mount/cifs stuff, but looks my assumption is wrong. i have tested different methods, and strange, if a direct use cli as `sudo mount -t cifs //share /mout/path -o domain=domainname,username="user",password="pass"`, it works, so looks not like the `legal ip` stuff, but if i write the config in `/etc/fstab` and `sudo mount -a` i still  got that error. but any way i got a workarount and thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

dont know why, but mount that with cmd directly in wsl2 terminal instead of config in `/etc/fstab` could work:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //share /mout/path -o domain=domainname,username="user",password="pass"
```